# LongPress on OSMDroid map is not working

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Im creating an OpenStreetMaps application using OSMDroid lib. I need LongPress gesture to add  markers into an OverlayItem array to show them all, but i can't access to LongPress anyway.

I have tried with GestureListener, overridden the onTouch event, using GestureDetector(which is deprecated nowadays) and I can't find a solution for this problem.

The only way i have get the gesture is through setOnLongClickListener, but I have to choose between having longpress or panning the map, and I'm greedy and I want both :p

Have anyone any ideas?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encounter a solution through **OSMBonusPack** library.

The object `MapsEventsReceiver` grants you a simple way to handle map's gestures.
You have to override `singleTapUpHelper` and `longPressHelper` methods and create a new overlay with this handler.

Here's the code:

```
MapEventsReceiver mReceive = new MapEventsReceiver() {

    @Override
    public boolean singleTapUpHelper(IGeoPoint arg0) {
     Log.d("debug", "Single tap helper");
     //your onSingleTap logic here
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPressHelper(IGeoPoint arg0) {
    Log.d("debug", "LongPressHelper");
    //your onLongPress logic here
    setMarker(arg0);
    return false;
    }
};

//Creating a handle overlay to capture the gestures
MapEventsOverlay OverlayEventos = new MapEventsOverlay(getBaseContext(), mReceive);
map.getOverlays().add(OverlayEventos);

//Refreshing the map to draw the new overlay
map.invalidate();


//I use this method to set the marker on touchPoint
    protected void setMarker(IGeoPoint arg0) {

touchPoint = (GeoPoint) arg0;
targetPoint = touchPoint;
path.addPoint(targetPoint);

//Listener to handle item's(markers) events
 myOnItemGestureListener = new OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongPress(int arg0, OverlayItem arg1) {
    Log.d("debug", "Testing long tap on item");
    //your item onLongPress logic here
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    Log.d("debug", "Testing single tap on item");
    //your item onSingleTap logic here
        return true;
    }
};

itemarray.add(new OverlayItem("Marker " + cnt, "Info about marker " + cnt, touchPoint));

ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem> overlayDeItems = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(getBaseContext(), itemarray, myOnItemGestureListener);
map.getOverlays().add(overlayDeItems);

overlayDeItems.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);
map.invalidate();
itemarray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
   cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setupGestureListener() {
    GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            //do something
        }
    };

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), gestureListener);
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried before with GestureDetector and GestureListener. I got no errors on source code, but I didn't get response from events at logcat.

Comment: Where are you putting the code?  I have this in a class extending MapView.